Problem on the cardinality of the two subsets of a bipartite graph
I am given a bipartite graph $(A \cup B, E)$ with the following property: for every $a  \in A$ and $b \in B$ for which $ab \in E$, $d(a) \geq d(b)$. I must show that $ |A| \leq |B|$.
I realised that this is not true in general, since if A has as many vertices as B connected to each other and extra isolated vertices then the hypothesis is satisfied but the conclusion is wrong. Am I missing something here? So the only way I saw to prove this is further assume that the graph is connected. My idea was to try proof by contradiction, and so assume that $|A| > |B|$ and start specifically with the graph which connects every vertex of A with at least one vertex of B and using the pigeonhole principle show that there is at least one vertex of B with degree greater than one of its connected vertices which contradicts our hypothesis and then argue that every other connected bipartite graph can be constructed from this one graph by adding edges which always causes the same issue.
Any feedback on my approach or alternative and/or better ways to prove it?

Well spotted. One needs to assume that there are no isolated vertices or equivalently that all vertices have degree at least 1, the statement isn't true otherwise.

Under the assumption that every vertex in $A$ has a neighbour in $B$, we can get a solution using the pigeonhole principle. Assume $|A|>|B|$. By the pigeonhole principle, there exists two vertices, say $a_1, a_2 \in A$, having a neighbour, say $b_1\in B$, in common. Since the graph is bipartite $$\sum_{a\in A}d(a) = \sum_{b\in B}d(b).$$ We thus have
\begin{align}
\sum_{a\in A}d(a) &\geq \sum_{a\in A\backslash \{a_2\}}d(a) +d(a_2)\\
&\geq \sum_{a\in A\backslash \{a_2\}}\max\{d(b):ab\in E\}+d(b_1)\\
&\geq \sum_{b\in B}d(b) + d(b_1)\\
&> \sum_{b\in B}d(b),
\end{align}
a contradiction, as desired.
